# How to improve and optimize Python Code for compiling images to Word file and saving as PDF

Tags: python, optimization

Background: I am new to Python, and just trying to automate my mundane tasks.

It's my first time writing a program using python (this program is executed via the command prompt, it's not a GUI yet). So, what happens is I have a picture file (Has a random file name, I'm manually renaming this to "receipt.jpg", by the way, so it can conform to the code) and a PDF file ("SOA.pdf", also renaming this manually). I convert the pdf to image, insert the two images in a Word document, then save the document.

Here then is the question. Can anyone check the code I wrote and make some recommendations on how to improve it? I feel like I repeated a lot of code, and just changed a single letter.

Also, I can't straight up convert the Word file directly to PDF since Microsoft's Azure Information Protection is on, and have to manually click "Internal".

Sorry for the long question. Here's the code:

```
#import libraries
from lib2to3.pytree import convert
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
#from docx2pdf import convert

#convert SOA.pdf to JPEG image named SOA.jpg
images = convert_from_path('SOA.pdf')
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].save('SOA.jpg', 'JPEG')

#store receipt.jpg as picture1, and SOA.jpg as picture2
picture1 = "receipt.jpg"
picture2 = "SOA.jpg"

#Access the properties of the pictures
img1 = Image.open(picture1)
img2 = Image.open(picture2)

#Store widths and heights of images to variables
width1 = img1.width
height1 = img1.height

width2 = img2.width
height2 = img2.height

#Create a document
document = Document ()

#Insert the picture1 into the document, width and height are calculated
document.add_picture(picture1,width=Inches(width1/260),height=Inches(height1/260))

#Center picture1
last_paragraph = document.paragraphs[-1]
last_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

#Insert the picture2 into the document, width and height are calculated
document.add_picture(picture2,width=Inches(width2/260),height=Inches(height2/260))

#Center picture2
last_paragraph1 = document.paragraphs[-2]
last_paragraph1.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

#Save the document as word file (.docx)
document.save('Receipt and SOA.docx')

#convert ('Receipt and SOA.docx','Receipt and SOA.pdf')
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add a function `add_picture` to simplify the code and remove the duplication. Something like this:

```
def add_picture(document, picture):
  img = Image.open(picture)

  #!todo: Check that this file exists. I.e. that next actions with img are correct

  #Store widths and heights of images to variables
  width = img.width
  height = img.height

  #Insert the picture1 into the document, width and height are calculated
  document.add_picture(picture, width=Inches(width/260), height=Inches(height/260))

  #Center picture
  last_paragraph = document.paragraphs[-1]
  last_paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

In this case you'll call this function twice:

```
#Create a document
document = Document ()

add_picture(document, "receipt.jpg")
add_picture(document, "SOA.jpg")
```

May be you will prefer to add one more function – `get_img_size(picture)`:

```
def get_img_size(picture):
      img = Image.open(picture)

      #!todo: Check that this file exists. I.e. that next actions with img are correct
    
      return img.width, img.height
```

After this your `add_picture` will be even simpler.

Also I'd extract the constant 260 to the very beginning of your code. It is right to avoid duplication of constants. So, I'd put something like `img_size=260` somewhere upper.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I would try this and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: This worked! I would compare my code with yours, so that I can implement the DRY principle in my future projects. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ilya, can I have some favor?

Comment: Hi @Jace, please add more details if you expect an answer.